# Calculating time difference in seconds

Tags: vb.net

I am using following code to calculate time difference.  I want to display it in seconds, not in HH:MM:SS 
Please advise.

```
Dim myTime = DateTime.Parse("15:40:00 PM")
    Dim vrNowTime = DateTime.Parse(TimeOfDay)
    Dim result = vrNowTime - myTime
    Label1.Text = vrNowTime & "   " & myTime
    MsgBox(result.ToString)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `result.TotalSeconds` (and round it if you want an integer number to be displayed).

Also you may want to write simply:

```
Dim result as TimeSpan = Now() - myTime
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use

```
Dim Result = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second,Time1,Time2)
```

Comment: Use of old VB global functions is discouraged in .NET